# Understanding: The factors of the upper central series of a torsion-free nilpotent group are also torsion-free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While trying to proof the following statement I got stuck.

*The factors of the upper central series of a torsion-free nilpotent group are also torsion-free.*

The problem is quite similar to the following question and among the answers of the related question there is also a short proof regarding my question. [Are lower central factors of torsion-free nilpotent groups torsion-free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809912/are-lower-central-factors-of-torsion-free-nilpotent-groups-torsion-free)

**Question 1: Why does the problem (according to the answer in the link) reduce to showing that $G/Z(G)$ is torsion-free?**

Now let me cite a different statement which is quite similar to the above answer given but leaves me with 2 more technical questions. Its from the book 'a course in the theory of groups' by Derek J.S. Robinson, page 137, theorem 5.2.19.

https://books.google.lu/books?id=zLfkBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA137&dq=factors%20of%20upper%20central%20series%20are%20also%20torsion%20free&hl=de&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q=factors%20of%20upper%20central%20series%20are%20also%20torsion%20free&f=false

**5.2.19** If the center of a group $G$ is torsion-free, each upper central factor is torsion-free.

**Proof.** Let $\zeta$G = $ \zeta_1G$ be torsion-free. It is enough (**Why?**) to prove that $\zeta_2G/\zeta_1G$ is torsion-free. Suppose that $x \in \zeta_2G$ and $x^m  \in \zeta_1G$ where $m>0$. [...] We have $[x,g]^m = [x^m,g] = 1$ , because $[x,g] \in \zeta_1G$ (**Why is $[x,g] \in \zeta_1G$ and how does the equation follow?**). Since $\zeta_1G $ is torsion-free, $[x,g] = 1 $ for all $ x \in G$, and $x \in \zeta_1G$.

So the way I see it, by reducing the proof to showing $G/Z(G)$ is torsion-free I can further reduce it to showing $\zeta_2G/\zeta_1G$ is torsion-free.

I hope to have clarified the question in a sufficient way. I'd be really thankful for any answer/hint/advice as I don't seem to find other related info on this one. Thanks for taking the time reading the question!

Comment: Question 1 is a straightforward induction on the length of the upper central series. Assuming that we can prove that $G/Z(G)$ is torsion-free, we can apply the inductive hypothesis to deduce that the factors of the upper central series of $G/Z(G)$ are torsion-free. But the factors of the upper central series of $G$ are the same together with $Z(G)$, and $Z(G)$ is torsion-free because $G$ is. $[x,g] \in \zeta_1G$ follows immediately from $\zeta_2 G/\zeta_1 G = Z(G/\zeta_1 G)$.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Still not sure how $ [x,g] \in \zeta_1G $ follows and how exactly $[x,g]^m = [x^m,g] = 1$ is obtain through this.

Comment: In general $g \in Z(G) \Rightarrow [g,h]=1$. $[x,g]^m = [x^m,g]$ follows from the standard commutator identities.